# How to use platform channels with FlutterView or Flutter.createFragment

Tags: flutter

I just saw the flutter roadmap mentioning a preview of adding flutter to [existing project](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps).

I am still not sure how to use platform channels when using `FlutterView` or `Flutter.createFragment`. Usually they are available in the `FlutterActivity` instance.

Answer (score 0):

You create a new instance of the channel and pass in your `FlutterView`. [This documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#step-3a-add-an-android-platform-specific-implementation-using-java) gives a good overview.